# How Can I Use IEnumerator.Reset()?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerator

How exactly is the right way to call [`IEnumerator.Reset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset.aspx)?

The documentation says:

> The `Reset` method is provided for COM interoperability. It does not necessarily need to be implemented; instead, the implementer can simply throw a `NotSupportedException`.

Okay, so does that mean I'm not supposed to ever call it?

It's *so* tempting to use exceptions for flow control:

```
using (enumerator = GetSomeExpensiveEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) { ... }

    try { enumerator.Reset(); } //Try an inexpensive method
    catch (NotSupportedException)
    { enumerator = GetSomeExpensiveEnumerator(); } //Fine, get another one

    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) { ... }
}
```

Is that how we're supposed to use it? Or are we not meant to use it from managed code at all?

Comment: Please never ever ever use exceptions for flow control...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

***never***; ultimately this was a mistake. The correct way to iterate a sequence more than once is to call `.GetEnumerator()` again - i.e. use `foreach` again. If your data is non-repeatable (or expensive to repeat), buffer it via `.ToList()` or similar.

It is a formal *requirement* in the language spec that iterator blocks throw exceptions for this method. As such, you ***cannot rely on it working***. Ever.

Comment: +1 I didn't know that part was a requirement in the language spec... then yeah, that's definitely a mistake. Kind of a bummer haha, it's sometimes so much easier to call it.

Comment: @Mark Gravell: Not all enumerators are iterator blocks. You can rely on Reset working if you are using a known IEnumerator implementation whose Reset method is known to work. For example, System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.

Comment: @phoog: Yeah I know what iterator blocks are, I just didn't know they had that *requirement*. :-)

Comment: @phoog is it explicitly documented to work...? And then you limit yourself to `List<T>`, not the interface - which is a bit of a pain. If you already know you have list-of-T, you also know that iterating it twice is just as easy...

Comment: Yes, it is explicitly documented to work (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335884.aspx).  I just chose List<T> as a quick example of a library type supporting the method.

Comment: @phoog but as mentioned: if you are tying into very specific implementations, you aren't *really* using IEnumerable as a general interface. It sucks that a method exists that is unusable... but; there it is

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Agreed, I'm just in a particularly pedantic mood today for some reason :=/

Comment: To my findings most classes implementing `ICollection<T>` (T[], List<T>, HashSet<T>, ...) return enumerators which implement `Reset()` in a working way.

Comment: @springy76 reality is that "most" simply isn't enough to be useful; either it is a useful part of the contract, or it isn't. With no way of testing whether it is supported (`bool ResetSupported {get;}`, for example), it is useless. IIRC, the compiler specification actually *requires* iterator blocks to throw `NotSupportedException` when `Reset()` is called.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend not using it. A lot of modern `IEnumerable` implementations will just throw an exception.

Getting enumerators is hardly ever "expensive". It is enumerating them all (fully) that can be expensive.

Comment: Depending on the issue, though, it *can* be expensive, at least relative to other normal operations. E.g.: Let's say you're wrapping calls to `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` -- those acquire system handles, which is a relatively expensive operation compared to something like array enumeration.

Comment: @MMehrdad: but then get the array *once*, and iterate over that. And when you need to restart, get a new iterator for the same array you already had.

Comment: @Stephen: Depends. If you're over the network, it can be expensive.

Comment: @Jalf: What if the array is very big though? You can't always save your data.

Comment: @Mehrdad: In that case, define the enumerator so that it only calls `FindFirstFile` when the first item is enumerated. That way, it acts just like every other enumerator.

Comment: @Mehrdad if the data is very big, the cost of GetEnumerator() is insignificant noise

Comment: @Marc: Not if you're doing something like iterating lots of files over an intermittent network connection. @Stephen: Yeah, that's a good *workaround*, though I'm not sure if it's a great *solution* per se.

Comment: @Mehrdad: what if that was the case? It sounds like the only solution that would satisfy your requirements is *magic*. It's not possible to have it both ways. You can *either* have the array in memory, making it cheap to iterate again and again, or you can load each element on demand, making it expensive to start over. No matter how those two options are wrapped, they're still all you have. If `Reset()` could be safely used, then it would still have to do one of those two

Comment: Either the enumerator could store the full array in memory, or it could call `FindNextFile` when you call `Next`, and `FindFirstFile` if you called `Reset`. There are no other options.

Comment: Most likely, depending on the implementation, either the enumerator is going to require a lot of memory (same as if you cached your very big list of files yourself) or calling Reset will be expensive (same as if you called GetSomeExpensiveEnumerator() again).

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's not a workaround. It's the expected way that enumerators work, especially in the current world of LINQ. `GetEnumerator` is expected to be a fast operation that captures its parameters and the first enumeration initiates the real work (network call, establishing db connection, etc).

Comment: @Mehrdad - then te API should be written to support that :) but not (IMO) by using Reset on the iterator

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PeopleEnum : IEnumerator
{
    public Person[] _people;

    // Enumerators are positioned before the first element 
    // until the first MoveNext() call. 
    int position = -1;

    public PeopleEnum(Person[] list)
    {
        _people = list;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        return (position < _people.Length);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public Person Current
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return _people[position];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```