# List<T>.Enumerator IEnumerator.Reset() method implementation

Tags: c#, list, ienumerator

Despite the fact, that [`IEnumerator.Reset` method should never be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968973/1163867) I found strange behavior of the method implementation within `List<T>`.

No matter how you examine the .NET Framework Source Code (tried with reference source and ILSpy) the method is implemented as following:

```
void System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset() {
    if (version != list._version) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
    }

    index = 0;
    current = default(T);
}
```

However, it looks like the method is never called at all! Consider the code:

```
var list = new List<int>(1) { 3 };
using (var e = list.GetEnumerator())
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.MoveNext());
    Console.WriteLine(e.Current);

    ((IEnumerator)e).Reset();

    Console.WriteLine(e.MoveNext());
    Console.WriteLine(e.Current);
}
```

It's pretty clear, that it should print `True` and `3` twice. Instead of that the result is

```
True
3
False
0
```

Any simple explanation I'm missing?

Comment: Turns out to be a new example of why mutable structs are evil. Mutable structs where the mutation happens through an explicit interface implementation are just a bit extra evil. But these nested `Enumerator` structs are normally only used by the C# compiler when it translates a `foreach` statement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Any simple explanation I'm missing?

Yes: you're boxing the `List.Enumerator` here:

```
((IEnumerator)e).Reset();
```

That takes a *copy* of the existing one and resets it - leaving the original in one piece.

To reset the *actual* enumerator, you'd need something like this:

```
var list = new List<int>(1) { 3 };
var e = list.GetEnumerator();
// Can't use "ref" with a using statement
try
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.MoveNext());
    Console.WriteLine(e.Current);

    Reset(ref e);

    Console.WriteLine(e.MoveNext());
    Console.WriteLine(e.Current);
}
finally
{
    e.Dispose();
}

static void Reset<T>(ref T enumerator) where T : IEnumerator
{
    enumerator.Reset();
}
```

It's tricky because it uses explicit interface implementation.

I haven't tested it, but I think that should work for you. Obviously it's a bad idea to *do* this...

EDIT: Alternatively, just change your variable type to `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerator<int>` to start with. Then it will be boxed *once*, and the `Reset` method will mutate the boxed value:

```
var list = new List<int>(1) { 3 };
using (IEnumerator e = list.GetEnumerator())
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.MoveNext());
    Console.WriteLine(e.Current);

    e.Reset();

    Console.WriteLine(e.MoveNext());
    Console.WriteLine(e.Current);
}
```

Comment: you also need to take it out of the `using` to pass it by reference.  Other than that change, I tested it real quick and this does work.

Comment: @Servy is right. He can simply box it in the beginning and then re-use the same box all the way. Edit: For example if he first upcasts the `List<>` to the interface type `IEnumerable<>` or `IEnumerable`, then uses that interface's `GetEnumerator()` method, the enumerator will already be in a box when he gets it, and he can re-use that box through the entire example.

Comment: Sure, You're right. I've just tested it with assigning `IEnumerator` to variable and it is actually reset. Thanks. I'll mark the answer as accepted asap.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Yes, I thought of that just as I was leaving the house :) Will edit it in.